# Linux bash thing

Tags: linux, bash

I try to create a little bash script, with which I have no experience. I try to do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
statut="na"
if [ $proc = 0 ]; then
    statut = "closed"
else
    statut = "opened"
fi
```

but I receive:
**./test.sh: line 4: statut: command not found**
Can you give me a hint? On Google I couldn't find something similar. All **if** examples are with **echo** not with variable assignation.
Thank you!

Comment: Your script will not parse if $proc is empty.  (eg, you'll get what appears to be a syntax error).  You can do what you want very simply with a one-liner:  test "$proc" = 0 && statut=closed || statut=opened

Comment: A better suggestion is to quote the variable: `if [ "$proc" = 0 ]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you're not following a syntax for assignment operator - you should remove spaces around '=' (and quote $proc):

```
#!/bin/bash
statut="na"
if [ "$proc" = 0 ]; then
    statut="closed"
else
    statut="opened"
fi
```

Comment: `$proc` should be quoted: `if [ "$proc" = 0 ]`